# Laravel : Entrust redirect & route protection

Tags: php, laravel

Im using Entrust to set user roles/permissions, this is working fine however if I am not logged in it is not redirecting to login page (it is blocking the pages with error message but I need it to redirect to login).

```
Route::group(array('middleware' =>'role:customer'), function ()
```

If I try and use auth middleware i just get a white page (with no error) when logged in however if not logged in it does now redirect to login page

```
Route::group(array('middleware' =>'auth','role:customer'), function ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the sintaxis for the Route::group should be:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:customer']], function() {
// ....
});
```

Or with array notation.

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => array('role:customer')), function() {
// ....
});
```

Add the array to your role:customer condition.

More detailed here: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#middleware

Comment: thanks but same result as my current code, it blocks the page but does not redirect to login page.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps? The extra lines in the middleware file? Just to check is not a config problem

Comment: Yes i added them all

Comment: Are you using the default authentication of L5? Can you post the error?

Comment: there is no error thats what i said it is just giving me a white page if I use `auth` . Yes default authentication of L5

Comment: Are you using the error pages? They are in resources/error/code.blade.php. If so try to create one named 403.blade.php, that's for the authorization request. The user will be prompted with the error that he/she needs authorization. Had a problem similar to this and solved it.